# CSS conditional margin-top when text is multiline

Tags: html, css

i'm working on the following page:

[image]

i want to align the "more" button to the bottom of the container. This works if the title is at-least 2 lines. how can i add some margin if the text is single line ?

here is my css:

```
.journeycontainer{
position: relative;
width: 940px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

```
.journey{
display: inline-block;
width: 400px;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 20px;
```

}

```
.journeycontent{
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
position: relative;
```

}

```
.journeybutton{
margin-top: 14px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
position: absolute;
```

}

basically i want change margin-top from journeybutton

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
.journeybutton{
   bottom:0px;
   left:0px
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here it is, don't use margin, use bottom:**

```
.journeybutton{
    bottom:0
    position: absolute;
}
```